# How to make PHP listening to the job tables

Tags: php, curl, cron, message-queue

I am working on the system which developed in php without framework.

It has the function is automatically run some jobs via third party api every night. It loops all the jobs in table and call api using curl.

```
// run cron job to loop this table
ID JOB
1 updateUser
2 getLatestInfo/topicA
……

//code

// if UpdateUser
loop user table and call api to get latest info…
Also other curl task will do here like send email / notification …
```

It works perfectly before. But recently we have many new users. It will call 50-100 API at the same time.

Each api call will take 10-20 seconds to respond, and we will retry the api if it is timeout.

I checked the log it totally take 3-4 hours for only first job (with many errors)

Although I can make the cron job for queueing the curl, like get first 5 curl and run them each 1 minutes. But if we keep increasing the users or task, and the third party api keep slow. It may take more hours to finish the task.

Is there any solution can make it keep listening to the job table, and run the curl one by one?
I want it can be auto Triggered  if new row is added to the table. (Like websocket?) and not single php to run and infinite loop ( to prevent some error occurred and need to rerun the php task manually )

(The API keys is in the php project, so I hope that I can do this in same project)

Comment: You've asked us to change the performance characteristics of a PHP script wich updates data. But you haven't shown us the code, nor provided any details of the data structures. "I want it can be auto Triggered if new row is added to the table" - isn't that what database triggers are for? It does rather sound like you are trying to olve the wrong problem here.

Answer (score 1):

PHP scripts need to be triggered in order to do something, they can't really "run in background" (I mean, they can, technically, but PHP isn't supposed to be used that way).

Instead, one of three options is usually used to do job management:

- call jobs on every call from web, along with the actual code to generate output
- use external web cron service to query specific URLs tied to job execution
- use local cron job on your system to call the php executable and have it execute jobs periodically

If you want an event based system, PHP is likely the wrong option. Depending on your DB system though you might be able to create a small wrapper code that subscribes to DB changes and is triggered on inserts, that then calls PHP again - but it's definitely a cleaner solution to use a more suitable programming language / environment.